# HttpConnection, UITableView and RunLoops and Loading from Disk

Tags: ios, uitableview, asynchronous, scroll, nsrunloop

I'm loading images in to a large grid on a table view. They are coming from the net, but once downloaded they are cached to disk.

I use this:

```
[_httpConnection scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
```

to ensure that they load into view whilst I'm still scrolling. Works fine.

However, when I revisit them and they are loading from disk - I don't have the same scheduleInRunLoop method to use ... well I might, but I don't know where it is.

Has anyone got any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.

I can dispatch my selector using modes:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(imageReadyToDeliver) withObject:nil afterDelay:0];
```

I can use

```
[self performSelector:@selector(imageReadyToDeliver) withObject:nil afterDelay:0 inModes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:NSRunLoopCommonModes]];
```